# Web API BasicHttpAuth with hashed password

Tags: asp.net, encryption, asp.net-web-api, hash, basic-authentication

So I have a web Api that authenticates users by username and password. The clients talking to the API will android phones that have an internal app on it to get / send some data from / too the api.

I have hashed passwords in the database with a salt. The connection between the client and the API will be SSL.

Now on the website (MVC) I log users in by generating a new hash and matching this against the hash in the database.

The some of the android devices will have a config file that locks the app to a specific user. Now I rather not store the password in plain text on the device and would like to encrypt the password.

The question now is what would be the best practise here on comparing the hashed password. I dont think its save to just send the plain password to the API or is it?

Comment: I have this exact same problem at the moment and found your question. I am using ASP.NET identity to manage my member database on the website end which is all stored in SQL Server etc. Then I have a mobile app talking to my MVC Web Api using basic auth, so it needs to pass a username and password across.

I don't wanna store a plain text password on the mobile devices. It would be really nice to be able to hash it in the same way that ASP.Net Identity does, then send that hash across from the mobile apps and compare it in the MVC Web API for authentication. So I don't store or send plaintext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's safe, because you're using SSL.

Basic authentication isn't acceptable for plain-text requests, but since HTTPS encrypts everything, it shouldn't be an issue.

Storing the password is a completely separate concern, as you've noted, and that should be encrypted as well, which it sounds like you'll have Android do for you. The only consideration is that you will have to do a reversible encryption to be able to send up the password itself to your API.

Basically:

1. (client-side) User enters creds
2. (client-side) Encrypt creds, store in configuration
3. (client-side) Read from config, decrypt creds
4. (client-side) File HTTPS request to API with Basic authentication type, using decrypted creds
5. (server-side) Hash (one-way encrypt, basically) the password, compare against database

That sounds like exactly what you've got, and I see no problem with it.

That all said, just for what it's worth, I'd be tempted to [implement an OAuth 2.0 server](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-oauth-20-authorization-server) for this particular use-case, so you don't have to think about persisting the password at all. That's a pretty big undertaking (sort of--it doesn't take too long with those instructions), and you should evaluate it on a case-by-case basis. But any time I have to worry about API authentication, I generally wind up either going with that, or wishing I had.

Comment: Thanks for the verification / explanation. The problem I'm facing here is that the API and the MVC application are in the same project. 

I had the use separate auth and went with basic auth from a tutorial. Since I prefer OAuth 2 as well I will spent some more time on implementing OAuth 2 frist since that looks to be the better solution here.

Comment: @FlorianSchaal Fair enough. Yeah, OAuth 2 is pretty complicated, but that (official) tutorial I linked to makes it super straight-forward. There are also lots of blog posts out there about doing OWIN implementations (like that). Nothing will ever be as easy as basic, but if you're comfortable supporting it, I think it's worth it. Especially for anything for use in production. Then, of course, you'd just store an access and/or refresh token in your config file. Still encrypted, but that's a little less scary.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider using something like JWT (JSON Web Token, http://jwt.io). You can have a client authenticate against your API, and if they provide the right credentials you can issue a token to them, which they can persist on local storage. They would then provide this token in the header of any API requests that require authentication. You can use OWIN middleware to intercept requests, check/validate the token and let the requests through to your controllers if you consider the token to be valid.